# Take data from websites using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to make a website like "Trovaprezzi" and fort this reason i have to take some data from different websites and show it in my website. 
The data that i have to take are some link.
I thought to use php and i tryed to use the CURL.
I had some problem because this  it isn't the better way (i downloaded all the page but i can't take only the link).
Someone can help me?

```
<?php 

function cURLcheckBasicFunctions() 
{ 
  if( !function_exists("curl_init") && 
      !function_exists("curl_setopt") && 
      !function_exists("curl_exec") && 
      !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false; 
  else return true; 
} 

/* 
* Returns string status information. 
* Can be changed to int or bool return types. 
*/ 
function cURLdownload($url, $file) 
{ 
  if( !cURLcheckBasicFunctions() ) return "UNAVAILABLE: cURL Basic Functions"; 
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  if($ch) 
  { 
    $fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
    if($fp) 
    { 
      if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ) 
      { 
        fclose($fp); // to match fopen() 
        curl_close($ch); // to match curl_init() 
        return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL)"; 
      } 
      if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE)"; 
      if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER)"; 
      if( !curl_exec($ch) ) return "FAIL: curl_exec()"; 
      curl_close($ch);
      fclose($fp); 
      return "SUCCESS: $file [$url]"; 
    } 
    else return "FAIL: fopen()"; 
  } 
  else return "FAIL: curl_init()"; 
} 

// Download from 'example.com' to 'example.txt' deal-title should-truncate
echo cURLdownload("http://www.groupon.it/browse/salerno?category=mangiare-e-bere&page=2", "example.txt"); 

?>
```

Comment: If you have to take some links and you actually have the page downloaded, why don't you use a regex?

Comment: try phpdom library after fetching the data.. it will convert your html string into dom in php and than you can access links similar to javascript dom e.g $("a") .. regex is also possible but in case of regex you've to place lots of additional checks .. I will recommend phpdom library..

Answer (score 0):

Check [Parse Web Pages with PHP script](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications)
. Might be useful for you.